# wordpress get_children won't work after pre_get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

A little help here with `get_children` function. `pre_get_posts` hook filter the main_query. After that I called `get_children` to get the attachment image but I ended up giving an 0 array result.

function.php

```
 function cstm_get_posts() {
        if ( is_post_type_archive( 'tent' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );
        return;
       }
     }
 add_action('pre_get_posts', 'cstm_get_posts' );
```

archive.php

```
 $attachments = get_children( array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
    ));
foreach($attachments as $attch){
 code display image here
}
```

Code above is just a snippet.

Anyway if I don't use `pre_get_posts` the `get_children` works fine. But I need the `pre_get_posts` to filter the query.  Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: what's the output of a `var_dump($post->ID)` just before your get_children call?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function cstm_get_posts($query) {
  if ( is_post_type_archive( 'tent' ) &&  $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );
    return;
  }
}
```

Added the parameter `$query` to the function.

Comment: no hope. still wont work.. the pre_get_posts works fine it display the posts but the get_children dont work 0 array return..

Comment: Sorry. I can't think of anything else that might fix it.

Comment: You need to return `$query` after making your modification. I'll attempt to edit the answer